# Why can't I add a foreign key that references from a composite key from the parent table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a table that has a 2 keys that are primary and foreign key at the same time that also references from another table.

```
CREATE TABLE public."restaurantProduct"
(
  "restaurantId" bigint NOT NULL,
  "productId" bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT "restaurantProduct_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("restaurantId", "productId"),
  CONSTRAINT "restaurantProduct_productId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("productId")
      REFERENCES public.products ("productId") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,
  CONSTRAINT "restaurantProduct_restaurantId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("restaurantId")
      REFERENCES public.restaurant ("restaurantId") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
```

Now I want to create another table called `custOrders` and use the `restaurantProduct.restaurantId` as foreign key but it gives me an error of **Error: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced talbe "restaurantProduct"** when I already have assigned `restaurantProduct.restaurantId` as a primary key. Also couldn't add `UNIQUE` to the `restaurantProduct.restaurantId` because a restaurant can have multiple products. I could redesign the database but I was just wondering if there is any way for it to work with this design alone?

Comment: A foreign key must include **all** columns from the referenced primary key.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name So you mean I have to include thee ```restaurantProduct.productId``` as a foreign key to my ```custOrders``` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I already have assigned `restaurantProduct.restaurantId` as a primary key

No, the column is not a primary key. It is *part of* a composite primary key. There can be multiple rows in your `restaurantProduct` table with the same `restaurntId`, as long as they have different `productId`s.

> I want to create another table called `custOrders` and use the `restaurantProduct.restaurantId` as foreign key

As the error messages already states, you cannot do that. You can however make it reference `restaurant.restaurantId`.

If you really want to make an order reference a `restaurantProduct`, you will need two columns - one for the `restaurantId` and one for the `productId`, and then have a composite foreign key which will reference *both* columns in `restaurantProduct`.